# MySQL Master Slave Replication only seems to be updating the binary logs on the slave

Tags: mysql, replication, percona

I have a very strange issue, I've setup Master / Slave replication with the slave being a Percona Cluster node.

Everything seems to be running correctly however no data appears in the slave databases and the data files themselves are not growing on the slave.

Oddily though i can see the filesize of the binlogs growing quite a lot on the slave (nothing else runs on this server at the moment).

My question is this.. During Master / Slave replication Does InnoDB / XtraDB cache a certain amount of data in the slave's binlogs before flushing it to the actual database?

If so can I configurre this "flushing".

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Binlog files are not directly used by Galera for replication, but the subsystem is (for its own replication protocol). Make sure that you have have activated `log-slave-updates` on the slave. Additionally, although it should work with the default STATEMENT format, due to some problems found in the past (autoincrement values working differently in Galera), I would recommend doing replication in `ROW` format.

If this doesn't work, we can try something else (are the binary logs increasing or are the relay logs increasing? -log slave updates should not be up by default; is the SQL thread stopped?; are you trying to replicate non-innodb tables?)